# Return N matching results from array using OR function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking to create an excel formula that runs through an array, and returns N matching results. i.e. I would have this formula first in cell A1 (for example), and it would return the first matching result. When I drag it down to cells A2, A3, etc. it returns the 2nd and 3rd matching result respectively. I currently have a formula that does this much:

```
INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081,AGGREGATE(15,3,(Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081="TRUE")/(Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081="TRUE")*(ROW(Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081)-ROW(Sheet2!$AA$1)),ROWS($R$73:R73))))
```

However, I am trying to use the OR function, so instead of just checking if a range of cells is TRUE or FALSE (this is currently done with helper cells/columns), I want to just be able to check the range for if it matches any of the following conditions:

- Cells whose value is over 999999
- Cells whose value is 0
- Cells whose value is negative (<0)

My attempt is below:

```
INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10081,AGGREGATE(15,3,(OR(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081>999999,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081=0,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081<0))/(OR(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081>999999,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081=0,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081<0))*(ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081)-ROW(Sheet2!$B$1)),ROWS($P$73:P73))))
```

This does not work however because the 3rd argument of aggregate() needs to be an array, and I used an OR function which evaluates as a boolean. With this being said I am not sure how to properly integrate an OR functions to check for the above 3 conditions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using? Also, could you show an example of the data and expected output?

Comment: The version of Excel that the server that will run this uses (this is an automatically generated report) uses Excel 2016. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/SKp87JI.png) is an example of input, and [here](https://i.imgur.com/AEZwxZb.png) is an example of output. To clarify, these examples of what I am expecting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition will do an **OR** function equivalent on each entry. So:

```
(myRng>999999)+(myRng<=0)
```

will return an array of `{1..0}` depending on whether your criteria are met.

To make the array for the `AGGREGATE` function, something like:

```
1/((myRng>999999)+(myRng<=0))*myRng
```

Comment: This ended up working for me. I actually just replaced the `Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081="TRUE"` with `(Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081>999999)+(Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$10081<=0)` and it ended up working out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365 and have access to the FILTER function, you could use FILTER to return the array. Each OR condition can be enclosed in parentheses and separated with a `+`, as described here:

[FILTER function - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Specifically:

> ...we're using the FILTER function with the addition operator (+) to return all values in our array range (A5:D20) that have Apples OR are in the East region...

Without knowing too much about your data, something similar to this should return the correct array (which actually doesn't need to be aggregated with small if you want to return all of the matched rows).

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10081,(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081>999999)+(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081=0)+(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10081<0))
```

**HOWEVER**... I just saw your comment saying this would be used on Excel 2016, so FILTER won't work (I'll leave it in the answer in case it helps others).

In Excel 2016 (and in Excel 365), you can use Power Query, since it seems you're really just trying to find rows that meet specific criteria.

I created some sample data:

[image]

Now just select any cell in the data and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range to open the Power Query Editor with a query on your data.

In the Power Query Editor, filter the value on the criteria you want to use:

[image]

Now use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook:

[image]

Last step is to make sure that the query is refreshed an an appropriate interval.

Put your cursor in the query results and go to Query>Properties and configure the refresh properties as you prefer:

[image]